# Spart streaming with kafka code inside foreachRdd is not executing if I have function executed LOCALLY

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have setup spark 2.2 locally and working with scala

spark session config is below

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("My application")
  .config("es.nodes", "localhost:9200")
  .config("es.index.auto.create", true)
  .config("spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate", "1")
  .config("spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition", "7")
  .master("local[2]")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

I am running spark on my local machine

when i do

```
  kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
   calledFunction(rdd)
 })


def calledFunction(rdd: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]): Unit ={

 rdd.foreach(r=>{
 print("hello")})
}
```

for above code on my local machine "hello" is not printing but all jobs are being lined up.

if i change my code to

`kafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
       rdd.foreach(r=>{
     print("hello")})
     })`

then it's printing  "hello" on console.

can you please help me here what is the issue?

Comment: Can you help with the return type of kafkaStream?  When I am running with spark 1.6 and dstreams it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When running with spark 1.6 its printing hello in console.
For reference here is the sample code

```
val message = KafkaUtils.createStream[Array[Byte], String, DefaultDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc,
  kafkaConf,
  Map("test" ->1),
  StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY
)
val lines = message.map(_._2)
lines.foreachRDD(rdd => {calledFunction(rdd)})


def calledFunction(rdd: RDD[String]): Unit ={
  rdd.foreach(r=>{
    print("hello")})
}
```

Hope this helps. As I am not able to regenerate the same issue with spark 2.0 for now, due to dependency mismatch.